# Login page - automatic clear submission of previous entries

Tags: html, class, input, types, placeholder

Is someone know how to automatic clear submission of previous entries in the fields?

Which it is in my opinion remember by the browser.

Thank you. 
Robert﻿

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a couple options:

1. Rename your form fields so the browser does not recognize them.  It seems most browsers offer to remember the fields with attribute name='username' and name='password' -- use any other naming convention and your problem will be solved.
2. Use JavaScript to clear the field after the page loads.  The browse populates the fields after the page loads.

Another consideration: This is a browser function that the user elected to perform; disabling it is not very user-friendly.

Comment: Thank you very much.

I spent all day searching for google. Such a simple solution. Thank you.

Receive nice greetings from Slovenia.

Robert.

p.s. have a nice weekend.